# Is there a way to drop a User Defined Table type that is already bound to a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an user defined table type (UDTT) that is already bound with a stored procedure which uses it as a input parameter. I have made a mistake in UDTT structure but I cannot alter UDTT so when I tried to delete it, SSMS complaints that its bound to store procedure so it cannot be deleted. Is there away to delete my UDTT?

thanks

Comment: You need to drop all procedures and other database objects that use that user-defined type before you can drop the type itself.

Comment: yea i had that in mind, but i wondered any other technique .. but thanks problem solved

Comment: marc_s solution worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is required on the drop, and what I normally do is set myself a template script that follows this execution:

-- Table builds or the type

```
if object_id(N'dbo.<tablename>') is null
begin <create table chunk> end
```

-- Proc Drops

-- UDTT Drops

-- UDTT Adds

-- Proc Adds

Then if you ever need to Alter a proc, you just seek it on that script and execute the script again.  Since there is no saved data in a procedure, this solves type overlooks as well as recompile options needing processed.  I found it to make development as well as testing much more conducive.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy work around here.  I use SSMS, and select

```
SCRIPT AS > CREATE TO > NEW QUERY EDITOR WINDOW.
```

This gives a script to create.  I then rename the existing data type rather than deleting it. Make whatever changes are needed to the recreate script, and execute.

You can then drop the renamed data type.

Its a bit of a work around, and an alter command would be better, but this does the job.

Comment: You cannot drop the renamed data type because it's still in use, you also have to change the stored procedure before dropping it.